How to uninstall rosdep2?
Im doing a robotics course in my local university using ROS2 Jazzy Jalisco.  I accidently installed rosdep2 onto my linux distro however I was speaking with my course coordinator and hes said to use rosdep instead due to configuration issues with rosdep2.  I tried to find how to uninstall rosdep2 but cannot find it.  Does anyone know how to do this so I can install rosdep instead.

If you use apt to install rosdep2, check if it's there then delete it
dpkg -l | grep rosdep  #list any rosdep related package


sudo apt remove python3-rosdep2 # remove rosdep2

If you used pip to install, then do this:
pip list | grep rosdep # list any rosdep installed via pip
pip3 list | grep rosdep  # list any rosdep installed via pip3 (python3)


pip uninstall rosdep  # or pip3

```

